# PHP Calculate centrality of nodes in a network

Tags: php, json, matrix, graph, dijkstra

I'm looking for a way to calculate the closeness- and the betweenness-centrality for a set of network nodes.

As input I have a json-object with the start-node end-node and the edge-information:

```
[{
    "publication": 4,
    "origin": 10,
    "destination": 11
},

 ....,

{
    "publication": 5,
    "origin": 10,
    "destination": 12
}, {
    "publication": 8,
    "origin": 12,
    "destination": 13
}]
```

As using a neighbor matrix gets inefficent for very large datasets, I'm looking for an alternative way to calculate the centrality. Would Dijkstra's algorithm be an option since I have an undirected/unweighted graph? And how would I implement it to use this json as input?

Comment: dijkstra's algorithm is for *weighted* graphs, how is this weighted?

Comment: your data is also not in a matrix...

Comment: You can use Dijkstra's algorithm . Also Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't care if you're using an adjacency list or an adjacency matrix as long as you abstract this detail away using an appropriate data structure, you will just suffer some speed penalty (which is the tradeoff to avoid the space penalty you have when using a matrix for the underlying graph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started you can do the following:

```
$edgeList = json_decode($thatJSONDataYouHaveInTheQuestion,true); 
$graph  = [];
foreach ($edgeList as $edgeData) {
    $graph[$edgeData["origin"]][$edgeData["destination"]] = isset($graph[$edgeData["origin"]][$edgeData["destination"]])?$graph[$edgeData["origin"]][$edgeData["destination"]]+1:1;
    //$graph[$edgeData["destination"]][$edgeData["origin"]] = isset($graph[$edgeData["destination"]][$edgeData["origin"]])?$graph[$edgeData["destination"]][$edgeData["origin"]]+1:1 //Uncomment for undirected graphs
}
```

Note that multi-edges are indicated that number at `$graph["sourceN"]["targetN"]`
Now you have a very very simple graph structure. You can do things like:

```
function containsEdge($graph, $source, $target) {
     return isset($graph[$source]) && isset($graph[$source][$target]) && $graph[$source][$target] > 0;
}
```

Or basically do whatever you need to do to implement Dijkstra's algorithm in PHP.

The nodes are given by `array_keys($graph)` for example or all adjacent edges to a node are given by `array_keys($graph["node"])`

Comment: This results in an "undefined offset" error in the if-condition